# Representing an ArrayList in a TextView

Tags: java, android

I have created an `ArrayList` in an Android.

```
//creating an `ArrayList` of string type named words

ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("one");
    words.add("two");
    words.add("three");
    words.add("four");
    words.add("five");
    words.add("six");
    words.add("seven");
    words.add("eight");
    words.add("nine");
    words.add("ten");
```

Now the elements of this `ArrayList` are to be displayed in a `TextView`. 
I have declared a `LinearLayout` named `rootView`-

```
LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
```

This is the code to display the first element of the `ArrayList` in the `TextView` -

```
TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
        wordView.setText(words.get(i));
        rootView.addView(wordView);
```

Now my question is: To display all the elements of this `ArrayList`, we will create individual `TextViews`s (with all `TextViews`s having a different name). 
If the name of any declared `TextViews`s matches with any another `TextViews` then an error occurs.

But when we use loops to display the elements of this `ArrayList` then we write something like this -

```
    for (int i = 0;i<words.size();i++){
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
        wordView.setText(words.get(i));
        rootView.addView(wordView);
    }
```

This gives no error. So inside loops, we have declared a single `TextViews` named `wordView`. Every time the loop runs, a new `TextView` with same name `wordView` is created, why does it not show any errors? Whenever we manually create `TextViews` there is a error whenever the name matches. Why this is so?

Comment: Its basic Java you cannot duplicate a variable name in same Block.

Comment: Have you considered if you're going about this in the right way? Wouldn't a `RecyclerView` be better for representing a list?

Answer (score 0):

The variable wordView is no longer available once it goes out of scope.

When your loop runs for the next time, compiler doesn't see this variable and allow you to create a new variable with same name.

Comment: Thanks!!
I got this. Thanks a lot!